# Oauth 2.0 and NEW Google spreadsheets API with PHP

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

I am building a web application using PHP and am receiving an "Access Token is invalid" error when trying to authenticate with Oauth 2.0 using the **New Google Spreadsheet API**. I am able to authenticate fine with the **Old Version** of the Google Spreadsheets API. Is this a known bug or has  the procedure for authenticating with the Spreadsheets API changed since version 3.0? Any help is appreciated, and thanks in advance!